# How to efficiently calculate log-returns

Tags: c#, .net, class, math, return

I have a multi-dimensional array `double[,] results` where each column represent a price time series for particular items (e.g. car, house...). I would like to calculate the log-returns for each time series as 
Log(price_t / price_t1) 
Where t>t1. So I will generate a new time series of log-returns for each column of `double[,] results`. 
How can this be done in C# in a efficient way? The amount of data is large and I was trying a solution like:

```
for(int col = 1; col <= C; col++)
{
     for(int row = 1; row <= R; row++)
     {
         ret = Math.Log(results[row+1;col]/ results[row;col])
     }
}
```

where C and R are the numbers of columns and rows in `double[,] results`. 
This solutioh runs quite slowly and seems very inefficient. Any suggestion how to perform a similar calculation faster?

I saw that in languages like MATLAB one can vectorize the code and simply divide the original matrix by another one that is just lagged by one element. Then take the log of the entire matrix that results from the division. Is it doable in C# and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computer has multiple cores you can easily improve the speed of your computation. To try it out myself I started by creating this function:

```
Double[,] ComputeLogReturns(Double[,] data) {
  var rows = data.GetLength(0);
  var columns = data.GetLength(1);
  var result = new Double[rows - 1, columns];
  for (var row = 0; row < rows - 1; row += 1)
    for (var column = 0; column < columns; column += 1)
      result[row, column] = Math.Log(data[row + 1, column]/data[row, column]);
  return result;
}
```

I benchmarked this function with an input array of 1,000 x 1,000 values. On my computer the execution time of 100 calls was around 3 seconds.

Because the body of the loop can execute in parallel I then rewrote the function to use [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Double[,] ComputeLogReturnsParallel(Double[,] data) {
  var rows = data.GetLength(0);
  var columns = data.GetLength(1);
  var result = new Double[rows - 1, columns];
  Parallel.For(0, rows - 1, row => {
    for (var column = 0; column < columns; column += 1)
      result[row, column] = Math.Log(data[row + 1, column]/data[row, column]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

On my computer with 4 cores (8 logical cores) the execution of 100 calls takes around 0.9 seconds. This is slightly more than 3 times as fast indicating that only the physical and not the logical cores are able to compute the logarithm.

Modern x86 CPU's have special instructions called [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) that allow you to vectorize certain computations. I would expect that MATLAB uses these instructions and that might explain why you experience much better performance in MATLAB compared to your own C# code.

To test SSE I tried [Yeppp!](http://www.yeppp.info/) that has bindings to C#. The library is available on NuGet as a prerelease and has a logarithm function. SSE instructions only works on one-dimensional arrays so I rewrote the baseline function:

```
Double[] ComputeLogReturns(Double[] data, Int32 rows, Int32 columns) {
  var result = new Double[(rows - 1)*columns];
  for (var row = 0; row < rows - 1; row += 1)
    for (var column = 0; column < columns; column += 1)
      result[row*columns + column] = Math.Log(data[(row + 1)*columns + column]/data[row*columns + column]);
  return result;
}
```

With the same input and 100 iterations, execution time now seems to be slightly less than 3 seconds indicating that a one-dimensional array might improve performance slightly (but logically it should not unless it is the extra argument checking that affects the execution time).

Using Yeppp! the function becomes:

```
Double[] ComputeLogReturnsSse(Double[] data, Int32 rows, Int32 columns) {
  var quotient = new Double[(rows - 1)*columns];
  for (var row = 0; row < rows - 1; row += 1)
    for (var column = 0; column < columns; column += 1)
      quotient[row*columns + column] = data[(row + 1)*columns + column]/data[row*columns + column];
  var result = new Double[(rows - 1)*columns];
  Yeppp.Math.Log_V64f_V64f(quotient, 0, result, 0, quotient.Length);
  return result;
}
```

I was unable to find a function to perform vectorized division using Yeppp! so the division is performed using "normal" division. However, I still expect the logarithm to be the most expensive operation. Initially performance was horrible with 100 iterations taking 17 seconds but then I noticed that there was an issue in Yeppp! about bad performance when running as a 32 bit process. Switching to 64 bit improved performance significantly resulting in around 1.3 seconds of executing time. Getting rid of the two array allocations inside the function (which was repeated 100 times) lowered execution to around 0.7 seconds which is faster than the parallel implementation. Using `Parallel.For` to do the multiplication lowered execution time to around 0.4 seconds. If Yeppp! had a way to perform division (which SSE has) you might get even lower execution time perhaps resulting in a ten fold speed increase.

Based on my experiments with SSE you should be able to achieve considerable performance improvements. However, you should probably pay attention to precision if that matters. An SSE log function might provide slightly different results compared to the .NET implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So do you think that with Parallel.For I would still get worst performance than vectorized computation?

Comment: @mickG: I am guessing here, but I would expect SSE to be much faster. Only problem is that you have to implement the logarithm using SSE yourself and you will have to make trade-offs between execution time and precision. I believe that Intel have a library you can use but I do not know about its availability and how complicated it is to use from C#.

Comment: I see, so there is no immediate way to improve the calculation. I'll try the Parallel.For which seems to be a great suggestion anyway. Is the Parallel.For worth using in any conditions ore there is a minimum amount of calculation over which the overhead is compensetated by running in parallel? I remember that in R when running in parallel for small loops tgere was actually a worst performance if compared with non-parallel execution. Only big loops benefit from parallel execution. Is there something similar to consider in C# or can I always use Parallel.For?

Comment: @mickG: You are correct that there is an overhead to parallelizing so it should only be used when there is a significant advantage which is the case when there are 1,000 rows that can be computed independently and each row takes a non-trivial amount of time to compute. I have also updated my answer after doing some tests using SSE and the results seems to contradict my previous statement about the advantages of using SSE. It would be interesting to see someone with more knowledge about the matter to provide an answer to your question.

Comment: @mickG: After having more fun with SSE I have learned that it is in fact quite fast. Using it properly from managed code may still lead you down a rough path but the end result may be worth it.

Comment: This looks great, thank you. I'll try Yeppp! and see if it's easy to use.  So it should basically allow me to vectorize the code to some extent?

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a rule of thumb to use when deciding when it is worth executing in parallel and when it's better not to?